# Unable to validate two patches in same cell of excel

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

```
Install-Module -Name ImportExcel
$data = Import-Excel C:\\pATCHING\\pATCHES.xlsx

$Wupdate = get-wmiobject win32_quickfixengineering -ComputerName $env:computername

if($Wupdate.HotFixID -eq $data[1].Patches)
{
write-Host "System is Compliant in patching parameter" -ForegroundColor Green

}
else
{
write-Host "System is Non-Compliant in patching parameter" -ForegroundColor Red

}
```

Please help to validate two patches from same cell.
[Excel Sheet Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HARjP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Loop through $data, filter out elements where patches = 'na' and split the patchinfo in the cell by the delimiter ",", verify if $Wupdate.HotFixID contains eq value:

```
$csv | ?{$_.patches -ne 'na'} | %{
    $_.patches -split "," | %{
        If ($Wupdate.HotFixID -contains $_.trim()){
            write-Host "System is Compliant in patching parameter" -ForegroundColor Green
        }
        Else {
            write-Host "System is Non-Compliant in patching parameter" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
}
```

The better way to do it:

```
#filter out where patches has value NA, split patches by delimiter ",", trim
$refPatches = $csv | ?{$_.patches -ne 'na'} | %{($_.patches -split ",").trim()}

#Compare referenceList of patches with installed patches and get elements present in referenceObject but missing in differenceObject
$compare = compare-object -ReferenceObject $refPatches -DifferenceObject $Wupdate.HotFixID | ?{$_.sideindicator -eq '<='}

#If compare has elements system is non compliant
If ($compore){
    write-Host "System is Non-Compliant in patching parameter" -ForegroundColor Red
}
Else {
    write-Host "System is Compliant in patching parameter" -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's working but there is two output if two patches with delimiter. I want only one output if any of them is missing/incorrect,system will be non-compliant.

Comment: sure, write-host outputs this message foreach patch... I only took over your logic ;-) But I will adjust

Comment: In the second code, it's giving system is compliant even though patches no. cell is blank or incorrect kbID. In case of cell is blank or incorrect pacth no., the system should be non-compliant.